# Function for comparing 2 CSV for missing elements

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I'm writing a function to compare two CSVs, but I'm getting errors as soon as I get to the compare part.
I want to point out only those elements who are listed in one of both.

Actual code

```
function Compare ($location1, $location2)
{
    #work in progress   
    $CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path $location1 -UseCulture
    $CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path $location2 -UseCulture
    $Compared = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CSV1 -DifferenceObject $CSV2 |
                select -ExpandProperty InputObject |
                sort
    [void] $CSV1
    [void] $CSV2
    return $Compared
}
```

and a snippet from the two CSVs:

Snippet A:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Snippet B:

```
a
b
c
d
e
h
f
g
h
i
j
```

Those are for testing purpose to see if it works, but for now it doesn't even start compare.

The two CSVs get loaded correctly as I looked up in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about it like this:

i've added a columnname on the first row called "Name". So with that set , you can access it as a property.
So

```
$CSV1 = $null
$CSV2 = $null

$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\pos\reference.csv' 
$CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\pos\difference.csv'

$dif = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CSV1 -DifferenceObject $CSV2 -Property Name

foreach($y in $dif){
   if($y.SideIndicator -eq "=>"){
    write-output $y.name "Is present in the difference but not in reference."
   }
   if($y.SideIndicator -eq "<="){
    write-output $y.Name "Is present in reference but not in difference"
   }

}

<# content csv1 (reference.csv)
Name
a
b
c
5
d
e
f
g
9
#>
<#content csv2 (difference.csv)
Name
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
#>
```

this would give me the output :

```
h Is present in the difference but not in reference.
i Is present in the difference but not in reference.
j Is present in the difference but not in reference.
k Is present in the difference but not in reference.
l Is present in the difference but not in reference.
m Is present in the difference but not in reference.
n Is present in the difference but not in reference.
o Is present in the difference but not in reference.
p Is present in the difference but not in reference.
5 Is present in reference but not in difference
9 Is present in reference but not in difference
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid compare-object does not work like that. From what I understand, you are trying to find the unique items in both. The easiest way is to add both CSVs together and do a `select-object -Unique` on the property you want to get the unique for.

```
($csv1 + $csv2).Name | Select-Object -Unique
```

Here I have assumed that the column name for data in the CSV is 'Name'

Comment: That would require an even more elaborate script. An easy way is to add another column to your csv files [either manually or programatically] with the corresponding file name in each line. Then once you add it, each data will have its origin in the newly added column.
You will need extra logic where the data exists in both files or it will cause conflict.

Comment: That sounds quite hard and confusing tho, so there isnt a easier way to get this working?